# Sharepoint 2013 - How to add Expand / Collapse button for 2 levels of grouping

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, custom-list, expand

I am a non-coder. I have a FAQ page which is a list view with Newsletter style. There are 2 levels of grouping used 1. Category 2. Question.

I am looking to add a toggle button or 2 buttons for Expand All and Collapse All. 
I tried using some codes from net but looks like they either work only with 1 layer of grouping or they do not expand or collapse a partially opened list.

If anyone has a solution for this , please help!

Comment: Coding using Javascript is really easy. To be honest its much easier to use compared to .NET. I really highly suggest try to learn it. Possibilities are endless.  I got no problem helping you to start if you want

Comment: Thanks Billy, yes I am always open to learn new stuff. Kindly help pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest learn first the basic of Javascript once your good with that try learning   doing basic like adding list item using Javascript by connecting to Rest API of SharePoint. Feel free to let me know if you got question and I also wanted to know what your level in terms of Javascript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Javascript in creating custom applications. I suggest stay away from server side code and try learning CSOM/JSOM because thats the trend right now.